# Delete key and value from a property file?

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

I want to delete key and value which is stored in a property file. How can i do that????

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First [`load()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) it using the [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(reader);
```

Then you can use the [`remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
properties.remove(key);
```

And finally [`store()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) it to the file.

```
properties.store(writer, null);
```

#### See also:

- [Properties tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: It is used to remove the key only if it is stored in a hashtable... I tried its not working........:(

Comment: Did you close the `Writer` afterwards the usual Java IO way?

Comment: Is their a way to do this in ant?

Comment: And how to do it if I use not the Properties but propertiesConfiguration to load file?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SolutionHash {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("student.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(reader);
        // System.out.println(properties);
        Enumeration e = properties.propertyNames();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()){
            String key = (String)e.nextElement();
            if(key.equals("dept"))
                properties.remove(key);
            else
                System.out.println(key+"="+properties.getProperty(key));
        }
        // System.out.println(properties);
    }   
}

OUTPUT:
name=kasinaat
class=b
```

Here you can see that I could remove a key value pair using remove() method.
However the remove() method is a part of the HashTable object.
It is also available in properties because properties is a subclass of HashTable