# Delete an entry from property file

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

How to delete key and value from property file? My property file has these contents:

```
key1=value1 
key2=value2
```

I used the below code to delete the entry `key2=value2`. After that, now the file has these values:

```
key1=value1 
key2=value2
Wed Mar 06 12:36:32 IST 2013 
key1=value1
```

java code to remove an entry:

```
FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
prop.remove(key);
prop.store(out1,null);
```

What is the mistake am doing. How to clear the whole content of the file before writing it.

Comment: Try `new FileOutputStream(file, *false*)`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225794/delete-key-and-value-from-a-property-file

Comment: Do not open the file in append mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete key and value from a property file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225794/delete-key-and-value-from-a-property-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The property file contents should look as follows:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

2) You are opening the file in append mode, this is wrong. It should be:

```
new FileOutputStream(file);
```

3) Close `out1` explicitly, Properties.store API:

> The output stream remains open after this method returns.

If you dont want to use Properties.store, you can write Properties directly

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("test.properties");
for(Entry e : props.entrySet()) {
    pw.println(e);
}
pw.close();
```

Comment: "prop.store(out1,null);" is this the only way to writing a property file?

Comment: it is specially designed method for saving Properties, what is special about it that it automatically converts chars to \uxxxx formmat when neecessary

Comment: in properties file, the key and value should be in this format.. "key = jdbc:dbname:dbtype:host:port/SID,uname,pass".. but while writing with store() method, its adding escape sequences.. so now the key and value "key = jdbc\:dbname\:dbtype\:host\:port/SID,uname,pass"... how to write it without escape sequences..

Comment: this behavior is according to Properties API, it will read it back OK. Anyway, I added an example how to write Properties directly.

Comment: thanks a lot.. its working.. but instead this, for(Entry e : props.entrySet()) { }, it should be, for(Entry<Object, Object> e : prop.entrySet()) { }